# Understanding what $d(f(x))$ means

Tags: calculus

I know that $d(f(x))$ is small change in $f(x)$. But why is $\int d(f(x))=f(x)$? We know $\int dx$ means adding little bit of $x$. But what does adding little bit of $d(f(x))$ actually mean? Since it is not on the $x$ axis?

Comment: What source are you learning from?

Comment: Calculus made easy

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing an image from the book where this statement is made.

Comment: One way to interpret ${\rm d}f(x)$ is $f'(x){\rm d}x$. You can think of ${\rm d}f(x)$ as the infinitessimal change in $f(x)$; if you integrate this over an interval you get the total change in $f(x)$ in that interval. So the definite integral $\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} {\rm d}f(x)=f(b)-f(a)$ is like saying $\int_a^b{\rm d}x=b-a$.

Comment: Could you please show mw how to visualize adding d(f(x)) together?

Comment: Sure. In this [expertly-made pic](https://i.imgur.com/Uu0v5gp.png), the light-blue segments added together represent the integral $df(x)$, and the darker-blue segment shows that this equals the total change in $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to write $y$ instead of $f(x)$ and $dy$ instead of $d(f(x))$. You are right: $f(x)$ is not on the $x$ axis. On an $xy$ plane, $f(x)$ and $d(f(x))$ are on the $y$ axis. Now, if you are comfortable with integrating $dx$, then you can integrate $dy$ in the same way.

Comment: I can't understand it,why is it justified to treat dy in the same way as dx where x is independent and y is dependent variable?

Comment: Integral of $dx$ is the sum of very small elements on the $x$ axis. In order to calculate any integral, you need to have those very small elements. Similarly, if you have very small elements on the $y$ axis, you can calculate their sum, that is, their integral. If you already have $dy$ elements, which you wrote as $d(f(x))$ , then calculating the integral of $dy$ is just their summation. In short: integral of anything is the sum of very small elements of that thing, be it $x$ , or $y$ , or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Let's pick a function for a concrete thought experiment.

Let $f(x) = x^2$ and let's sample it at the integers.

`0   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 ...`

Then list the differentials, like $df(x)$:

`1   3   5   7   9  11  13  15  17    ...`

Now, let's take the cumulative sum, like $\int df(x)$:

`0   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 ...` (noting that $f(0)=0$, so we can start at $0$)

$f(x)$ is restored!

Moreover, this is true at any sampling rate, so let the rate go to infinity and every point of $f(x)$ is reconstructed.

| $x$ | $f(x)$ | $df(x)$ | $\int df(x)$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |  |  |
| 0.01 | 0.0001 | 0.0001 | 0.0001 |
| 0.02 | 0.0004 | 0.0003 | 0.0004 |
| 0.03 | 0.0009 | 0.0005 | 0.0009 |
| 0.04 | 0.0016 | 0.0007 | 0.0016 |
| 0.05 | 0.0025 | 0.0009 | 0.0025 |
| 0.06 | 0.0036 | 0.0011 | 0.0036 |
| 0.07 | 0.0049 | 0.0013 | 0.0049 |
| 0.08 | 0.0064 | 0.0015 | 0.0064 |
| 0.09 | 0.0081 | 0.0017 | 0.0081 |